# Hide column names in shiny table

Tags: css, r, shiny, formattable

Is there a way to hide column names of a formattable? I thought about

- changing an attribute in the formattable options. Didn't find something about it in the documentation or SO.
- changing the font color to white for the header. I guess this may be an easy task for a CSS expert. I couldn't find the right sources to do it as a layman.

Maybe there is another option that I didn't think of? Thanks for your help in advance.

Example code below. The right table's header should be hidden.

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)

df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], B = 1:10)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderFormattable({
    formattable(df)
  })

  output$table2 <- renderFormattable({
    formattable(df)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
      h6("Table with header"),
      formattableOutput("table1")
    ),
    column(6,
      h6("Table without header"),
      formattableOutput("table2")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

> Additional: If there is a way to set cell borders like in Excel for the
>   right table, solutions to this problem would also be appreciated.

Comment: The `DT` package might be helpfull https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly hiding, but here is my simple suggestion:

```
output$table2 <- renderFormattable({
  names(df) <- c("_", ".")
  formattable(df)
})
```

Any help to your problem?

Comment: No, I need to hide the column names or change the font color. In the original problem, I need the them for further formatting in the `formattable` function. The column names change generically every week and there are much more columns.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#table2 th {display:none;}"))
```

Note that you will need to manually set the widths of your columns as they will collapse to the smallest width without text overflowing to a new line.

What I've done here is used some CSS to tap into table2's properties. I access the header properties by declaring `th` after stating the table's ID. Any additional css for the header can go after the `;`.

Comment: You also mentioned changing the header color too. You could do this similarly by changing `display:none` to `color:#ffffff`.

Comment: You could also set the font size to 0px, as well, by replacing `display:none` with `font-size:0px`.